# Upload file and access $_FILES

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file on some directory. The directory is recorded in the database. However, the code cannot read `$_FILES` i get null value everytime i try to upload files,. but the other input data are recorded to the database,. what happen is I cannot record the name of the file in the database its just blank.

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-upload'])){ 
    $record_title = $_POST['record_title'];
    $record_recieved_date_time = $_POST['record_recieved_date_time'];
    $record_checked_date_time = $_POST['record_checked_date_time'];
    $record_approved_date_time = $_POST['record_approved_date_time'];
    $record_status = $_POST['record_status'];
    $record_remarks = $_POST['record_remarks'];
    $record_type = $_POST['record_type'];
    $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO records (record_id , record_title ,    record_recieved_date_time , record_checked_date_time , record_approved_date_time , record_status  ,record_remarks , file , record_type)
            VALUES (NULL, '$record_title' , '$record_recieved_date_time','$record_checked_date_time','$record_approved_date_time' , '$record_status ' , '$record_remarks' , '$file' , '1')";

    if (mysqli_query($dbconfig, $sql)) {
        header('Location:memberAWP.php');
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($dbconfig);
    }
}
```

here is the Form, im using modal with the help of bootstrap

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data name="loginform"   class="form-horizontal">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="record_title"> TITLE </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="record_title" name = "record_title" placeholder="Enter Title">
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="record_recieved_date_time"> RECIEVED DATE / TIME </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                  <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="record_recieved_date_time"  name = "record_recieved_date_time" placeholder="Enter RECIEVED DATE / TIME">
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="record_checked_date_time"> CHECKED DATE / TIME </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                  <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="record_checked_date_time" name = "record_checked_date_time" placeholder="Enter CHECKED DATE / TIME">
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="record_approved_date_time"> APPROVED DATE / TIME</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                  <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="record_approved_date_time" name = "record_approved_date_time" placeholder="Enter APPROVED DATE / TIME">
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="record_status"> STATUS </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="record_status" name = "record_status" placeholder="Enter STATUS">
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="record_remarks"> REMARKS </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="record_remarks" name = "record_remarks" placeholder="Enter REMARKS">
                                </div>
                              </div>                                  
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="file"> ATTACHMENTS </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                  <input type="file" class="form-control" id="file" name="file" placeholder="Enter ATTACHMENTS">
                                </div>
                              </div>                                  

                              <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                  <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </form>
```

Comment: explain ur problem

Comment: Show us your HTML form too please. And you can't save `$file` in your database. Thats not how file upload works.

Comment: You need to save the file by using `move_uploaded_file()` and I would think you would want to use the actual name of the file NOT the temp name

Comment: Check if your form have enctype defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if( isset( $_POST['btn-upload'], $_FILES['file'] ) ){
    /*
        The sql is vulnerable to sql injection as you directly embed variables within the sql
        rather than using `prepared statements` so some extra care ought to be taken with the supplied
        data, perhaps use:

        filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'record_title', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );


    */
    $record_title = $_POST['record_title'];
    $record_recieved_date_time = $_POST['record_recieved_date_time'];
    $record_checked_date_time = $_POST['record_checked_date_time'];
    $record_approved_date_time = $_POST['record_approved_date_time'];
    $record_status = $_POST['record_status'];
    $record_remarks = $_POST['record_remarks'];
    $record_type = $_POST['record_type'];

    /*
        Access the uploaded file as an object for simplicity
        and use the values for saving the file etc
    */
    $obj=(object)$_FILES['file'];
    $file = $obj->name;
    $size = $obj->size;
    $tmp  = $obj->tmp_name;
    $type = $obj->type;
    $error= $obj->error;



    if( is_uploaded_file( $tmp ) && $error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK ){

        /* determine the location the file should be saved to */
        $destination = '/path/to/folder/' . $file;

        /* Save the file */
        $result = move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $destination );


        /* Proceed with the sql command if the file was saved OK */
        if( $result ){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO records ( `record_title`, `record_recieved_date_time`, `record_checked_date_time`, `record_approved_date_time`, `record_status`, `record_remarks`, `file`, `record_type`)
                VALUES ( '$record_title', '$record_recieved_date_time', '$record_checked_date_time', '$record_approved_date_time', '$record_status', '$record_remarks', '$file', '1' )";

            $result = mysqli_query( $dbconfig, $sql );

            if( $result )header('Location:memberAWP.php');
            else echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($dbconfig);

        }
    }
}
```

As was pointed out in a comment, ensure that the form has the correct `enctype` attribute set - for file uploads it should be `enctype='multipart/form-data'`

Unless you use the `move_uploaded_file()` function the file will remain in the `tmp` directory for a limited time before garbage collection removes it and the reference to the file ( in the db ) will no longer be valid.

Comment: i try to use your code,. however its still not working,. i cant upload the file which result to failure to record the other data in the database

Comment: I have JUST seen your HTML code - you are missing the closing quote from `enctype="multipart/form-data` ~ that should be `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: men,. i've been working for hours for this problem,. THANK YOU SO MUCH,. i think i need i coffee break,

Answer (score 0):

There are some basics thing you should know when working on file uploading.

1) You should define encryption type in your form for example

```
 <form action="demo_post_enctype.asp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

2) Next you must use move_uploaded_file(source,destination) function in order to upload your file.

Comment: what im trying to do is get the file data,. which i cannot record on my database,. and when i am trying to move_upload_file() function its not moving aswell,. i think the problem is in the $_FILES funtion

Comment: i have posted another answer bellow first try this if it works for you i will further provide you assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" name="loginform"   class="form-horizontal">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="record_title"> TITLE </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="record_title" name = "record_title" placeholder="Enter Title">
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="record_recieved_date_time"> RECIEVED DATE / TIME </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                  <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="record_recieved_date_time"  name = "record_recieved_date_time" placeholder="Enter RECIEVED DATE / TIME">
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="record_checked_date_time"> CHECKED DATE / TIME </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                  <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="record_checked_date_time" name = "record_checked_date_time" placeholder="Enter CHECKED DATE / TIME">
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="record_approved_date_time"> APPROVED DATE / TIME</label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                  <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="record_approved_date_time" name = "record_approved_date_time" placeholder="Enter APPROVED DATE / TIME">
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="record_status"> STATUS </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="record_status" name = "record_status" placeholder="Enter STATUS">
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="record_remarks"> REMARKS </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="record_remarks" name = "record_remarks" placeholder="Enter REMARKS">
                                </div>
                              </div>                                  
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="file"> ATTACHMENTS </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-10">
                                  <input type="file" class="form-control" id="file" name="file" placeholder="Enter ATTACHMENTS">
                                </div>
                              </div>                                  

                              <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                  <button type="submit" name="btn-upload" value="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </form>
```

change html code after try this code

```
 if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']))
 { 
   $record_title = $_POST['record_title'];
    $record_recieved_date_time = $_POST['record_recieved_date_time'];
    $record_checked_date_time = $_POST['record_checked_date_time'];
    $record_approved_date_time = $_POST['record_approved_date_time'];
    $record_status = $_POST['record_status'];
    $record_remarks = $_POST['record_remarks'];
   // $record_type = $_POST['record_type'];
    $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
//echo  $fileName= $_FILES["file"]["name"];
echo  $sql = "INSERT INTO records (record_id , record_title ,    record_recieved_date_time , record_checked_date_time , record_approved_date_time , record_status  ,record_remarks , file , record_type)
            VALUES (NULL, '$record_title' , '$record_recieved_date_time','$record_checked_date_time','$record_approved_date_time' , '$record_status ' , '$record_remarks' , '$file' , '1')";

 if (mysqli_query($dbconfig, $sql)) {
        header('Location:memberAWP.php');
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($dbconfig);
    }

}
```

try this code

Answer (score 0):

First of go to your project folder and create a new folder with the name of "uploads". the try the following code. if file upload get successfully done you can write your query in the IF block where we used echo for success. but first try this. i hope it works for you.

```
<?php
      if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
        $record_title = $_POST['record_title'];
        $record_recieved_date_time = $_POST['record_recieved_date_time'];
        $record_checked_date_time = $_POST['record_checked_date_time'];
        $record_approved_date_time = $_POST['record_approved_date_time'];
        $record_status = $_POST['record_status'];
        $record_remarks = $_POST['record_remarks'];
        $record_type = $_POST['record_type'];
        $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];

        $target_dir = "uploads/";
        $path = $target_dir.$file;
        $tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp,$path))
        {
          echo "File successfully uploaded"; 
        }
        else
          echo "file did not upload"; 
    }

    ?>


    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="loginform"   class="form-horizontal">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="record_title"> TITLE </label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="record_title" name = "record_title" placeholder="Enter Title">
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="record_recieved_date_time"> RECIEVED DATE / TIME </label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                      <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="record_recieved_date_time"  name = "record_recieved_date_time" placeholder="Enter RECIEVED DATE / TIME">
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="record_checked_date_time"> CHECKED DATE / TIME </label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                      <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="record_checked_date_time" name = "record_checked_date_time" placeholder="Enter CHECKED DATE / TIME">
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="record_approved_date_time"> APPROVED DATE / TIME</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                      <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="record_approved_date_time" name = "record_approved_date_time" placeholder="Enter APPROVED DATE / TIME">
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="record_status"> STATUS </label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="record_status" name = "record_status" placeholder="Enter STATUS">
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="record_remarks"> REMARKS </label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="record_remarks" name = "record_remarks" placeholder="Enter REMARKS">
                                    </div>
                                  </div>                                  
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="file"> ATTACHMENTS </label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                      <input type="file" class="form-control" id="file" name="file" placeholder="Enter ATTACHMENTS">
                                    </div>
                                  </div>                                  

                                  <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                      <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```